# How to stop an submit event? which called twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my form code:

```js
$("form").on('submit', function(e) {
  console.log('Form submitted')
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

$("#search1").on('submit', function(c) {
  console.log('Form submitted 1')
  c.preventDefault();
  c.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Form submit with JS function</h2>
<form name="search">
  Name:
  <input type="text" name="name1" /> Age:
  <input type="text" name="age1" />
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<form name="search1" id="search1">
  Name:
  <input type="text" name="name1" /> Age:
  <input type="text" name="age1" />
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**Problem:** when i try to submit my form it work for both form i just want to submit form having id search1 on search1 click and search on search click but when i click it is submitting both form and as i click twice it work twice for each form again and again submission

Comment: `$("form").on...` will target any element named form.

Comment: Make the `form` selector less generic, or use `$('#search1').off('submit').on('submit, function() ...`

Comment: well `$("form")` selects all the forms so working as expected. You could remove the event handler, but it would be better to not select it at all.

Comment: @epascarello any code suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var formOne = document.getElementsByName('search');
var formTwo = document.getElementsByName('search');
document.getElementsByName("SubmitFirstForm")[0].addEventListener("click", function () {
  formOne[0].submit();
  alert('formone submitted');
});
document.getElementsByName("SubmitSecondForm")[0].addEventListener("click",function(){
  formTwo[0].submit();
  alert('formtwo submitted');
});
//or you can simply use the below commented code in place addEventListener
/*document.getElementsByName("SubmitFirstForm")[0].onclick= function () {
 formOne[0].submit();
   alert('formone submitted');
};
document.getElementsByName("SubmitSecondForm")[0].onclick= function () {
 formTwo[0].submit();
   alert('formtwo submitted');
};*/
```

```html
You don't require to submit the form with JQuery here as the input type is **submit** in the form.
 You only require to submit the form with JavaScript or JQuery when the input type is **button**.
 And submit a form by its form name is very good practice using JavaScript.

e.g.

<h2>Form submit with JS function</h2>
<form name="search">
  Name:
  <input type="text" name="name1" /> Age:
  <input type="text" name="age1" />
  <input type="button" name="SubmitFirstForm" value="Submit" />
</form>

<form name="search1" id="search1">
  Name:
  <input type="text" name="name1" /> Age:
  <input type="text" name="age1" />
  <input type="button" name="SubmitSecondForm" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<h2>Form submit with JS function</h2>
<form name="search" id="search"> <--! set id for first form-->
  Name:
  <input type="text" name="name1" /> Age:
  <input type="text" name="age1" />
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<form name="search1" id="search1">
  Name:
  <input type="text" name="name1" /> Age:
  <input type="text" name="age1" />
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

$("#search").on('submit', function (e) { // change the element selector as id selector. 
   console.log('Form submitted')
   e.preventDefault();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

$("#search1").on('submit', function (c) {
   console.log('Form submitted 1')
   c.preventDefault();
  c.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

`$("form")` will catch both of your form in your html code. So you should set id for both forms and try to catch this forms `submit` events by id, and it will works.

Answer (score 0):

try this,its working for me

```
<form name="search" id="search1">
            Name:
            <input type="text" name="name1" /> Age:
            <input type="text" name="age1" />
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

        <form name="search1" id="search2">
            Name:
            <input type="text" name="name1" /> Age:
            <input type="text" name="age1" />
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
```

**js code:**

```
$("#search1").on('submit', function (e) {
        alert("Form1 submitted");
        console.log('Form1 submitted')
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });

    $("#search2").on('submit', function (c) {
        alert("Form2 submitted");
        console.log('Form2 submitted')
        c.preventDefault();
        c.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
```

Comment: not working form me every time i click on submit first form called

Comment: i think you have used same id selector for multiple times in your page.make sure  same id selector used in the page.

Comment: same id selector??

Comment: example : $("#search1") is used in many places.id selector is unique for the page.you should not use same id name on multiple times in same page.

Comment: i have checked its unique and the second form shows after Ajax call